# Handle dropdown's focus state

Tags: javascript, focus

I am currently making a dropdown component in pure JavaScript. When the user click on the dropdown toggle, the content gain focus and its content is being displayed. When the user click outside of it, then the content loses its focus and it gets hidden.

So far, it works great. However, I am encountering two problems.

The first one is that when an element inside the dropdown is clicked (eg: anchor tags), the dropdown loses focus, which it shouldn't.

The second one is that when the dropdown toggle is clicked while the dropdown content is being displayed, the dropdown should close instead of closing then re-opening due to the click registered on the dropdown toggle.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown toggle</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" tabindex="0">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://example.com">My profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://example.com">Log out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative; 
}

.dropdown.is-open .dropdown-content {
    display: block; 
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

JS:

```
class Dropdown {

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.toggle = this.element.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
        this.content = this.element.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

        this.bindings();
    }

    bindings() {
        this.toggle.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));
        this.content.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
        this.content.addEventListener('focusout', this.close.bind(this));
    }

    open(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.element.classList.add('is-open');
        this.content.focus();
    }

    close(e) {
        this.element.classList.remove('is-open');
    }

    handleKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            this.close(e);
        }
    }

} 

document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(dropdown => new Dropdown(dropdown));
```

I have been trying to get my head around on how I would solve these issues without any luck. Any idea on how to solve these issues?

Comment: Adding the CSS might make the question a little clearer. And I think you might want the `toggle` method on classList instead of add and remove. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Highly appreciate your feedback. I added the CSS. As for the toggle, I am no expert, but I think it is more explicit to use add and remove, especially since they are both in a different function (not like both were in a toggleDropdown method for example). Is there any particular reason as to why I should use toggle instead?

Comment: @scorchy you should definitely add toggle at least to the open function which will prevent  your second issue as each time you click the link it will toggle the class, rather than just add the class. Which is the behavior your expecting.

Comment: @ZackSunderland I just tried but it didn't work. When you click on the dropdown toggle, it opens the dropdown. Then when you click back on it, the dropdown closes since it lost focus (focusout listener calls the close method), but since you clicked back on the dropdown toggle, it toggles it back to is-open, same as to what classList.add would do. Am I missing something?

Comment: @scorchy you're right. I'm looking at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found a solution that works. Try the code below

```
        class Dropdown {

            constructor(element) {
                this.element = element;
                this.toggle = this.element.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
                this.content = this.element.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

                this.bindings();
            }

            bindings() {
                this.toggle.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));
                this.content.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
                this.element.addEventListener('focusout', this.onFocusOut.bind(this),true);
            }
            onFocusOut(e) {
                if (!this.element.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
                    this.close(e)
                }
            }

            open(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.element.classList.toggle('is-open');
                this.content.focus();
            }

            close(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.element.classList.remove('is-open');
            }

            handleKeyDown(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                    this.close(e);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried and it solved the first problem. However, when clicking on the dropdown toggle, it should only close the dropdown instead of re-opening it back up. Would you know how to solve this issue by any chance?

Comment: @scorchy One last revision and everything is working for me. For clarification, I just updated the focusout event to be on the whole element rather than just the content. I also changed the add function to toggle inside of the open function. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Looks like its working fine to me, thank you a lot! I accepted your post as the answer.